# Base64 - CryptoStream with StreamWriter vs Convert.ToBase64String()

Tags: c#, base64, streamwriter, cryptostream

Following feedback from Alexei, a simplification of the question:

How do I use a buffered Stream approach to convert the contents of a CryptoStream (using ToBase64Transform) into a StreamWriter (Unicode encoding) without using Convert.ToBase64String()?

**Note:** Calling Convert.ToBase64String() throws OutOfMemoryException, hence the need for a buffered/Stream approach to the conversion.

Comment: Step 1: read what Base64 is, step 2: read and Base64 in blocks of correct size, step 3: profit... Side note: you could make your question much better if you remove all unrelated crypto/zip references and simply say "Copy large `Stream`/`byte[]` to file as Base64-encoded text"...

Comment: You're right. I was bogged down in the detail of the process and thinking it was hard, rather than approaching it logically. I'll modify the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should implement custom `Stream`, not a [TextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx). It is much easier to compose streams than writers (like pass your stream to compressed stream).

To create custom stream - derive from `Stream` and implement at least `Write` and `Flush` (and `Read` if you need R/W stream). The rest is more or less optional and depends on you additional needs, regular copy to other stream does not need anything else.

- In constructor get inner stream passed to you for writing to. Base64 is always producing ASCII characters, so it should be easy to write output as UTF-8 with or without BOM directly to a stream, but if you want to specify encoding you can wrap inner stream with `StreamWriter` internally.
- In your `Write` implementation buffer data till you get enough bytes to have block of multiple of 3 bytes (i.e. 300) and call `Convert.ToBase64String` on that portion. Make sure not to loose not-yet-converted portion. Since Base64 converts 3 bytes to 4 characters converting in blocks of multiple of 3 size will never have `=`/`==` padding at the end and can be concatenated with next block. So write that converted portion into inner stream/writer. Note that you want to limit block size to something relatively small like `3*10000` to avoid allocation of your blocks on large objects heap.
- In `Flush` make sure to convert the last unwritten bytes (this will be the only one with `=` padding at the end) and write it to the stream too.
- For reading you may need to be more careful as in Base64 white spaces are allowed, so you can't read fixed number of characters and convert to bytes. The easiest approach would be to read by character from `StreamReader` and convert each 4 non-space ones to bytes.

Note: you can consider writing/reading Base64 by hand directly from bytes. It will give you some performance benefits, but may be hard if you are not good with bit shifting.

Comment: Done pretty much all that. Going to be writing the Read shortly... Also went the bit-shifting method as I have a C++ background and it's not an issue for me to do it. :)

Just took me a while to get my head around the chaining of the streams.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using following to encrypt. I am using fileName/filePath as input. You can adjust it as per your requirement. Using this I have encrypted over 1 gb file successfully without any out of memory exception.

```
public bool EncryptUsingStream(string inputFileName, string outputFileName)
        {
            bool success = false;

            // here assuming that you already have key
            byte[] key = new byte[128];

            SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
            algorithm.Key = key;

            using (ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor())
            {
                CryptoStream cs = null;
                FileStream fsEncrypted = null;
                try
                {
                    using (FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(inputFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        //First write IV 
                        fsEncrypted = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                        fsEncrypted.Write(algorithm.IV, 0, algorithm.IV.Length);

                        //then write using stream
                        cs = new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                        int bytesRead;
                        int _bufferSize = 1048576; //buggersize = 1mb; 
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];
                        do
                        {
                            bytesRead = fsInput.Read(buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
                            cs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        } while (bytesRead > 0);

                        success = true;

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //handle exception or throw.
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (cs != null)
                    {                       
                        cs.Close();
                        ((IDisposable)cs).Dispose();                    

                        if (fsEncrypted != null)
                        {
                            fsEncrypted.Close();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            return success;
        }
```

Comment: This is not relevant to my problem. The main encryption pass using CryptoStream has already occurred. I've also pushed the results through a second CryptoStream to convert to Base64. I now need to write the resulting data using a Stream/buffered byte[] approach to a file using StreamWriter and Unicode encoding, in order to support legacy files.

Comment: I think you may use fsEncrypted to create StreamWriter object and write.                                                         using(var sw = new StreamWriter (fsEncrypted, Encoding.Unicode)) { // do as your requirement here      }

Comment: Actually... To preserve the Stream "using" pattern I'm going to write a Base64 conversion stream that does the Base64 conversion and the writing to the underlying stream in Unicode and then pass it a FileStream.